# PHP Tesseract Text Extraction

Tags: php, tesseract

I am trying to use [this library](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php)   to get the text from the attached image. But I have failed to get anything from this image.

```
<?php
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

    echo (new TesseractOCR('image.png'))
   ->run();
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have "Tesseract OCR" installed as described in that library readme?

Comment: I have just get the vendor folder using composer.

Comment: Then open https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php and note what the "Installation" section says.

Comment: And I am using XAMPP in Windows 10.

Comment: Installed this one- https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki keeping all default options. The Installer is- tesseract-ocr-setup-3.05.00dev.exe.